# cannot found web.xml error while restarting app in openshift

Tags: xml, openshift

First i was getting disk quato exceeded error on restarting the application in openshift, but then i got the following error

```
Starting jbossews cartridge

 The jbossews cartridge is already stopped
 rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/openshift/53798f90e0b8cd65bf000871/jbossews//conf/web.xml': No such file or directory
 Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/53798f90e0b8cd65bf000871/jbossews.
```

I tried clearing the temp files and log files then also getting the same error. I checked the location of the web.xml files, and it is not there, what should i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've stated the problem: the file does not exist so the deployment fails.
Try to manually create the file and everything should work:

```
$ touch conf/web.xml
```